# MSSQL Server Node.js error when inserting date from javascript into MSSQL Server

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I use node.js in Javascript with node-mssql module. I would like to create a Javascript new Date()-Object and set the date into mssql-Server in "createdAt" field. Here is my query:

```
const finishDoublettenAnzeige = async(req,res) => {
let requestObject = await createMSSQLConnection(mssql_doublettencheckui_config);
let date= new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace('T', ' ');

const query = 
`IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Doubletten WHERE documentId= ${req.params.id})
    UPDATE Doubletten SET done=1, createdAt=${date} where documentId=${req.params.id}
ELSE 
    INSERT INTO Doubletten (documentId, done, createdAt) VALUES(${req.params.id}, 1, '${date}')`;
    //requestObject.input('createdAt', sql.DateTime2, new Date());
await requestObject.query(query).then((result) => res.status(200).send(result)).catch(err=> res.status(404).send(err));
}
```

I have the problem, that nothing is being inserted in the "createdAt" field of  type Datetime2 in MSSQL Server. But the format seems to be right: `2019-06-13 14:39:56`

EDIT : I found the error, I was missing quotes around the date: `'${date}'` so that date was recognized as a string

Answer (score 0):

EDIT : I found the error, I was missing quotes around the date: '${date}' so that date was recognized as a string